# Usar google sheets como base de datos .json

Tags: javascript, array, api, google-hoja-de-cálculo, jsonarray

Como hago para usar una hoja de google sheets como base de datos en un proyecto con JS, usando la API de google, como llamar a los elementos demtro de un objeto en la array etc.

Comment: este [paquete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.